# How to execute OWASP ZAP `Spider` for a recorded and exported `Sites` and `Context` through Node

Tags: owasp, zap

I have recorded a flow and created/Exported a `Sites` and `Context` using OWASP ZAP Tool.
Now I need to run ZAP `SPIDER` on the records `Sites` with `Context` through NodeJS

I have done `npm install zaproxy`

now I need to know how can I access/Import the recorded `Context` and `Sites` in my code and execute `Spider` and generate Reports on it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I cover using the ZAP API in this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVnMh6AUkk&list=PLEBitBW-Hlsv8cEIUntAO8st2UGhmrjUB&index=14

Do you have to use the NodeJS client? Thats not really maintained by the ZAP core team and is currently out of date.

Comment: Thank you for link, will go through it and will try to come up with solution, but I some how have to use NodeJS, so is it out dated just because ZAP core team doesn't maintain it?

Comment: The node js code is in the ZAP repo https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/tree/develop/nodejs/api/zapv2 but was contributed by a non core team member and they havnt been updating it. Unfortunately the core team doesnt have enough experience in NodeJS:( We'd love someone else to take it on and will be v happy to support anyone who is interested in maintaining it. ZAP is a community project and we welcome new contributors :)